# Finding CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR

Tags: cuda, cmake, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

I am trying to set up [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/) trunk build with CUDA options enabled.

I believe I have installed CUDA correctly, following [these instructions](http://www.dickscheid.net/2011/10/19-cuda-ubuntu-1110/).

In the cmake options for the PCL build, some options are unrecognised:

[image]

Is there something I can manually set `CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR` to? Likewise for the other unfound options.

Comment: I don't have any experience with the project you are building, but for CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR, set it to directory which the SDK installer wrote it's contents into, usually your home directory if you accepted the default options. The other unset options I think you can safely it ignore, they applied to the now deprecated and removed CUDA device emulation features of the runtime API.

Comment: As I know CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR is got by system variable (is not set by FindCuda). So, if you does not want to set it through system vars you can set it for cmake. This default value is normal and c CUDA can work with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR` should be set to the direction in which you installed the NVIDIA's GPU Computing SDK.  The GPU Computing SDK is downloadable from the same page at NVIDIA where you downloaded CUDA.  By default, this SDK will install to `$HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK`.  Set it appropriately and then rerun cmake.

**Edit:**

The `CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR` variable is actually looking for the sub-directory beneath `$HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK` that contains the version of CUDA you're using.  For me, this is `$HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/CUDA/v4.1`.

Comment: This is no longer the case in 7.5?

Answer (score 0):

The source code for [FindCUDA.cmake](https://gforge.sci.utah.edu/gf/project/findcuda/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=%2Ftrunk%2FCMake%2Fcuda%2FFindCUDA.cmake&view=markup) gives some hints on how this path is found:

```
########################
# Look for the SDK stuff.  As of CUDA 3.0 NVSDKCUDA_ROOT has been replaced with
# NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT with the old CUDA C contents moved into the C subdirectory
find_path(CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR common/inc/cutil.h
  "$ENV{NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT}/C"
  "$ENV{NVSDKCUDA_ROOT}"
  "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\NVIDIA Corporation\\Installed Products\\NVIDIA SDK 10\\Compute;InstallDir]"
  "/Developer/GPU\ Computing/C"
)
```

I.e. check that NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT or NVSDKCUDA_ROOT environment variables are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux machine,..
Add **"$ENV{HOME}/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C"** to the 'find_path' options in FindCUDA.cmake module:  (usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake)

```
########################
# Look for the SDK stuff.  As of CUDA 3.0 NVSDKCUDA_ROOT has been replaced with
# NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT with the old CUDA C contents moved into the C subdirectory
find_path(CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR common/inc/cutil.h
  "$ENV{HOME}/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C"
  "$ENV{NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT}/C"
  "$ENV{NVSDKCUDA_ROOT}"
  "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\NVIDIA Corporation\\Installed Products\\NVIDIA SDK 10\\Compute;InstallDir]"
  "/Developer/GPU\ Computing/C"
)
```

cmake now finds my 4.0 SDK automatically.
But my build still fails to find cutil.h, even though it is there.  $HOME/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/cutil.h.  I had to add an include flag to the project to get it to finally work.  CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS : -I/**home/bill**/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc
Note: -I/**$HOME**/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc does **NOT** work.  (The env $HOME is set correctly.)